# What is a regular eigenvalue?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, terminology

I have read [here](https://mast.queensu.ca/%7Emath211/m211oh/m211oh94.pdf) that a simple eigenvalue is regular and I want to know what is a regular eigenvalue. I did search on google but couldn't find that exact term so I'm asking here.

Comment: The last two digits in the resolved document URL (which I've edited the question to use) appear to be page numbers; the one you cite is page 94. Going back to [page 93](https://mast.queensu.ca/~math211/m211oh/m211oh93.pdf), we find "An eigenvalue $\lambda_i$ of $A$ is called *regular* if $\nu_A(\lambda)=m_A(\lambda)$". (I suspect the "$\lambda$" should be "$\lambda_i$".) So, the question becomes: *How is this author defining $\nu_A$ and $m_A$?* Page 94 mentions "algebraic multiplicity $m_A(\lambda)$"; could $\nu_A$ be *geometric* multiplicity? ... Only 92 other pages to check! :)

Comment: Thank you Blue for putting a better link. I think $v_A$ is not geometric multiplicity. (Google search says:"The geometric multiplicity of an eigenvalue is the dimension of the eigenspace"; that can't be one for $\mathbb{R}^n$ unless $n=1$). By the way can you put a link in the comments to download all the pages at once or do I have to download them one by one?

Comment: (Replying to my past self) $v_A$ IS the geometric multiplicity and it can be 1 in $\mathbb{R}^n$ if there is only one eigenvector associated with the eigenvalue of that eigenspace.

Comment: If you chop-off the end of the URL you'll get to a [directory of files](https://mast.queensu.ca/~math211/m211oh/). Lots of .tex/.log/.aux files to ignore, but the .pdfs are clickable. Anyway ... Going back to [page 90](https://mast.queensu.ca/~math211/m211oh/m211oh90.pdf) yields reference to $\nu_A^p(\lambda)$ as the dimension of the "$p$-th generalized eigenspace"; with $p=1$ indicating the "usual" eigenspace. Just to be sure, we can click back to [page 88](https://mast.queensu.ca/~math211/m211oh/m211oh88.pdf) to find $\nu_A(\lambda_i)$ explicitly defined as the geometric multiplicity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of an $n \times n$ matrix $A$. We say $\lambda$ is a **regular** eigenvalue or **semi-simple** eigenvalue if its geometric and algebraic multiplicities are equal, i.e. if $ \dim \ker(A - \lambda I) $ equals the largest integer $m(\lambda)$ such that $ (t - \lambda)^{m(\lambda)} $ divides the characteristic polynomial $p_A(t)$ of $A$.

For a general eigenvalue $\lambda$, we have $ \dim \ker(A - \lambda I) \leq m(\lambda) $, and $\lambda$ is regular if and only if we can find a basis for $ \ker(A - \lambda I) $ of the maximum possible size, namely, the algebraic multiplicity $m(\lambda)$. Since the sum of $m(\lambda)$ over all eigenvalues $\lambda$ is exactly $n$, the matrix $A$ is diagonalizable if and only if every eigenvalue of $A$ is regular.

A simple eigenvalue $\lambda$ is automatically regular because $ 1 \leq \dim \ker(A - \lambda I) \leq m(\lambda) = 1 $.

Comment: Thank you user141240. Can you explain that part "For a general eigenvalue $\lambda$, we have $\dim \ker(A - \lambda I) \leq m(\lambda)$"? And is what I wrote in my 2nd comment to the question correct?

Comment: As you have said, $v_A(\lambda)$ IS the geometric multiplicity. Of course it can be 1, in which case the eigenspace is 1-dimensional and $\lambda$ is simple if and only if regular.

Comment: For the inequality, let $k=\dim\ker(A-\lambda I)$ and $\beta_0 = \{v_1, \dots, v_k\}$ be a basis for the eigenspace $\ker(A-\lambda I)$. Extend $\beta_0$ to a basis $\beta = \{v_1, \dots, v_n\}$ for the whole space. What can you say about the representation of $A$ with respect to $\beta$, after a change of basis? Moreover, the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is divisible by $(t-\lambda)^k$. Why?

Comment: From my knowledge, Representation of A changes according to the change of basis formula ($[A]_{\{v'\},\{w'\}}=[P_{w'\to w}]^-1 [A]_{\{v\},\{w\}}[P_{v'\to v}]$ where $A:V\to W$). And to the 2nd question, as I'm understanding it, we would need $(t-\lambda)$ to appear k times in the characteristic polynomial to get k eigenvectors. Which means the polynomial would be divisible by $(t-\lambda)^k$.